# Removing from a LinkedList

Tags: c#, linked-list

From the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195098/deleting-item-from-a-listtype) I asked, `RemoveAll` is the cleanest way to remove from a `List<>` based on a condition. Curious to know what is the best way to remove from a `LinkedList` as there is no `RemoveAll` function there.

```
List<ItemClass> itemsToErase = new List<ItemClass>();
    foreach(ItemClass itm in DS)
    {
           if(itm.ToBeRemoved)
                itemsToErase .Add(itm);
    }
    foreach(ItemClass eraseItem in itemsToErase)
    {
          DS.Remove(eraseItem );
    }
```

EDIT: DS is of type `LinkedList<ItemClass>`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While you can't remove nodes from a [LinkedList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) while iterating it with `foreach`, you can manually iterate the [LinkedList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) by following the [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be.aspx) property of each [LinkedListNode<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754.aspx). Just remember the next node of the node before removing it:

```
var list = new LinkedList<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
var node = list.First;
while (node != null)
{
    var next = node.Next;
    if (node.Value % 2 == 0)
        list.Remove(node);
    node = next;
}
```

---

*Extension Method:*

```
public static int RemoveAll<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }
    if (match == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");
    }
    var count = 0;
    var node = list.First;
    while (node != null)
    {
        var next = node.Next;
        if (match(node.Value))
        {
            list.Remove(node);
            count++;
        }
        node = next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
LinkedList<ItemClass> DS = ...
DS.RemoveAll(itm => itm.ToBeRemoved);
```

See also: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: And if you use this in more than one place, it's a great candidate for an extension method.

Comment: @svick: Good idea; extension method added.

Comment: I am new to extension method. Can you please how how to use this particular extension method for my case.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove an item from `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>` is to use one of the `Remove()` methods. However this operation is faster than removing an item form `List<T>` (`O(1)` instead of `O(n)`), since the operation can be performed locally. The items behind the removed item have not to be moved, only the two nodes before and after the removed item have to be linked together. `removed.Previous.Next = removed.Next; removed.Next.Previous = removed.Previous;`. This is done internally, since the `Previous` and `Next` properties are read-only.

Comment: While `Remove(LinkedListNode<T>)` is indeed O(1), `Remove(T)` is O(n), because it has to find the item to remove first.